# Failed to mount /data_

Tags: 18.04, mount

[image]

[image]

hello everyone,

I am having a problem in my server. it boots into emergency mode everytime. when I checked the media folder there is no /data_NAS option. data_NAS can be seen inside the root folder which I am not sure why. I would appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the contents of your `/etc/fstab` file and also post the output of `systemctl list-units | grep data_NAS`.

Comment: Hi i added all the necessary sections inside the question.

Comment: can you comment out that line, and boot, then do `mount /data_NAS` while connected to internet, see if it works? if so, maybe it doesn't wait for internet connection when mounting, in that case you can add `_netdev` to options

Answer (score 3):

Your `fstab` file is the problem: it is trying to mount an HTTP URL which I don't think is even possible, but in any case, this is what is giving you the error. So, since you don't want to mount anything on `/data_NAS`, just delete that line from `/etc/fstab` (the line mentioning `/data_NAS`) and reboot.

By the way, there is no reason to obfuscate a disk's UUID, there's nothing private or in any way sensitive about that.

Comment: thanks it worked but is there a way that I can try the connection from data_NAS

Comment: @ArasAhmedov that is a completely different issue. Please post a new question, and make sure to include (in the body of the question, and as text, not screenshots): the operating system you are running, the operating system of the NAS, the kind of access you have set up for the NAS, and the contents of your fstab file. _If_ the NAS is set up to share its drives using something like NFS or samba, then you will be able to mount it, but not by using some http URL like that.